# Need help with physics 2D Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, physics

I'm making a 2D game in Unity. Basically there's just a rocket that goes where ever the user touches. With the code that i have right now, the rocket instantly rotates towards the point and moves there straight.

```
Vector3 dir = targetPos - transform.position;
float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(dir.x, dir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
rb.MoveRotation(-rotZ);
thrust = 10.0f;
rigidbody2d.AddForceAtPosition(transform.up * Thrust, transform.up);
```

This code is placed in the Update function.

I want the rocket to start moving in which ever direction It's currently facing and slowly rotate towards the point as it goes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
float rotationSpeed = 1;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,Quaternion.euler(0,0,-rotZ), rotationSpeed);

rigidbody2d.AddForceAtPosition(transform.up * Thrust, transform.position - transform.up);
```

Thanks everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a coroutine and make it delay for some time and then activate the rotation function. The spawning position may be randomized using random.range

Comment: What do you mean by spawning position?

Comment: Sorry for that my bad I meant the direction could be randomized.

Comment: Why would i randomize the direction?  I want the rocket to move where user touches

Comment: Cause that's how I understood the last part of your question when you said "which ever direction"

Comment: I apologize once more for misunderstanding English isn't my first language

Comment: i meant that i want the rocket to start moving in the direction in which It's currently pointing then slowly rotate towards the touch point and move there.

Comment: Oh try using Quaternion.Lerp() it will make a smooth rotation over time, you can adjust the time

Comment: No problem mate. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Try using Quaternion.Lerp() it will make a smooth rotation over time, you can adjust the time

Comment: If you don't get the effect you want you might try a similar function Quaternion.Slerp().

Comment: I tried it but Lerp/Slerp requires 2 rotations. I have 1 rotation, that is the rotation of my rocket but i don't have destination rotation because the destination is just a touch on the phone's screen. How do i solve this?

Comment: You could create a variable that will be equal to Quaternion.LookRotation(TOUCH POSITION - transform.position) and then use this variable as the second rotation parameter for the Quaternion.Slerp(). Make sure your variable is in the Update function.

Comment: It doesn't work. The rocket sprite starts skewing

Comment: Try replacing your rotation speed with Time.deltaTime

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is control the rocket using steering behavior.

At every frame. You want to move the rocket towards its transform.forward, it might be transform.up in the case of 2d.

Then you want to lerp the rockets rotation towards the target location

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target), rotationSpeed);
```

RotationSpeed should be a number between 0 and 1. Like 0.3 for a fairly slow rotation

Comment: This  is what i did in Update function
targetPos = Input.mousePosition;
targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(targetPos);
rb.AddForceAtPosition(transform.up * Thrust, transform.up);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPos), 0.4f);

But as soon as i touch the screen, the rocket starts spinning really fast and skewing.